# Errors while running simple shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

Trying to run a simple shell script which consists of set of commands which I routinely execute to setup my Hadoop environmnent. First I'm connecting through '**ssh localhost**' before I execute these commands manually, I want to automate this process, I'm the doing the following which is resulting in the errors listed below. Please note I'm able to execute these commands manually from command prompt. Please help me out.

**What I did**

```
$sudo chmod 777 hadoop-startup-script.sh
$ssh localhost
$./hadoop-startup-script.sh
```

This results in the following errors

```
(~($))sh hadoop-startup-script.sh
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.204.0
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 3: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/hadoop: not found
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 4: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/start-all.sh: not found
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 5: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/hadoop: not found
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 6: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/hadoop: not found
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 7: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/hadoop: not found
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 8: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/hadoop: not found
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 9: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/hadoop: not found
hadoop-startup-script.sh: 10: hadoop-startup.sh: bin/hadoop: not found
```

**Contents of hadoop-startup-script.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash 
cd ~/hadoop-0.20.204.0
bin/hadoop namenode -format
bin/start-all.sh 
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input/oreilly
bin/hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/Dropbox/hadoop/hadoop-inputs/oreilly-programmingPig/*.* /user/hadoop/input/oreilly/
bin/hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/Dropbox/hadoop/hadoop-inputs/oreilly-programmingPig/NYSE_dividends  /user/hadoop/input/oreilly/
bin/hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/Dropbox/hadoop/hadoop-inputs/oreilly-programmingPig/baseball  /user/hadoop/input/oreilly/ 
bin/hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/Dropbox/hadoop/hadoop-inputs/oreilly-programmingPig/NYSE_daily  /user/hadoop/input/oreilly/
```

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: The first error is the one that matters, all the others derive from it since you're never got to the folder where the other commands could work. Maybe check the permissions on that folder?

Comment: Does `~/hadoop-0.20.204.0` exist? Run `ls -l ~/hadoop-0.20.204.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are telling you that the locations `~/hadoop-0.20.204.0`, `bin/hadoop` and `bin/start-all.sh` don't exist.

Did you mean `~/bin`, `/bin` or `~/hadoop-0.20.204.0/bin`? If you meant `~/hadoop-0.20.204.0/bin` then the first failing `cd` explains the the following errors. Check the name and permissions on the folder carefully.

Comment: OOps its typo in my cd command which was triggering the chain of erros. Sorry for bugging with such stupid question, correcting the hadoop folder name in the 'cd .. ' command did the trick.